# Pandas: select rows if keyword appears in any column

Tags: python, string, pandas

I know there is a relevant thread about searching for a string in one column ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975069/how-to-filter-rows-containing-a-string-pattern-from-a-pandas-dataframe)) but how does one use pd.Series.str.contains(pattern) across all columns?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'ids': [u'aball', u'bball', u'cnut', u'fball'],
'id2': [u'uball', u'mball', u'pnut', u'zball']})


In [3]: df[df['ids'].str.contains("ball")]
Out[3]:
     ids  vals
0  aball     1
1  bball     2
3  fball     4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `stack`

If you select just the things that might have `'ball'` which are columns that are of `dtype` `object`, then you can `stack` the resulting dataframe into a series object.  At that point you can perform `pandas.Series.str.contains` and `unstack` the results back into a dataframe.

```
df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).stack().str.contains('ball').unstack()

     ids    id2
0   True   True
1   True   True
2  False  False
3   True   True
```

Comment: Uses too much ram if I use 1.9 million records and 264 variables

Comment: Got it working with this:
df.loc[df.select_dtypes(include='O').stack().str.contains('text', na=False, regex=False, case=False).unstack().any(1)]

Answer (score 5):

Use [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for only object columns (obviously strings) with [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and `in`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
                   'ids': [None, u'bball', u'cnut', u'fball'],
                   'id2': [u'uball', u'mball', u'pnut', u'zball']})
print (df)
   vals    ids    id2
0     1   None  uball
1     2  bball  mball
2     3   cnut   pnut
3     4  fball  zball

mask = df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).applymap(lambda x: 'ball' in x if pd.notnull(x) else False)
#if always non NaNs, no Nones
#mask = df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).applymap(lambda x: 'ball' in x)
print (mask)
     ids    id2
0  False   True
1   True   True
2  False  False
3   True   True
```

Another solution is use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
mask = df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('ball', na=False))
#if always non NaNs, no Nones
#mask = df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('ball'))
print (mask)
     ids    id2
0  False   True
1   True   True
2  False  False
3   True   True
```

Then for filtering use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one `True` per rows or [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check all values per rows:

```
df1 = df[mask.any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
   vals    ids    id2
0     1   None  uball
1     2  bball  mball
3     4  fball  zball

df2 = df[mask.all(axis=1)]
print (df2)
   vals    ids    id2
1     2  bball  mball
3     4  fball  zball
```

Comment: @piRSquared - Yes, but then problem use `all`

Comment: @piRSquared - Change solutions for working with NaNs, Nones :)

Comment: Is there something more memory friendly? This uses all of my 64gb of ram (1.9 million records/264 variables)

Comment: @Cibic - If possible, use `regex=False`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37894064)

Comment: Also, this comes back with this error on latest pandas: "TypeError: ("argument of type 'int' is not iterable", 'occurred at index Code')"

Comment: I need the regex to make it case insensitive you see

Comment: @Cibic - hmm, some idea `mask = df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).applymap(lambda x: 'ball' in str(x).lower() if pd.notnull(x) else False)` or 
`mask = df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('ball', na=False, regex=False, case=False))`

Comment: For `case insensitive` is not necessary `regex=True`, just tested